# Adding a field to msgbuf

Tags: linux, message-queue, ipcs

I got an assignment to create a message queue in Linux. I need to use `msgnd()` and `msgrcv()` functions. Everything works if my message structure has two fields `mtype` and `mtext[]` but I need to add one more field an `int mpid`. But when I read the value from mpid it is just garbage from the memory. I searched for answers or examples but I only found structures with two fields. Can I even add more?

```
struct myBuff{
    long mtype;
    char mtext[255];
    int mpid;
};
```

code for the sender

```
void add_message(int id, struct myBuff buff){
    int size = strlen(buff.mtext) + 1 + sizeof(int)
    if (size > 255 + sizeof(int))
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    
    msgsnd(id, (struct msgbuf*)&buff, size, 0 | MSG_NOERROR);
}
```

code for the receiver

```
void check_message(int id, struct myBuff* buff)
{
    msgrcv(id, (struct msgbuf*)buff, 255 + sizeof(int), buff->mtype, 0 | MSG_NOERROR);
}
```

Comment: You should be using `sizeof(struct myBuff)` for the size arguments.You're reading and writing partial structs.